# Eslint doesn't recognize "as" operator

Tags: typescript, eslint

I'm having trouble understanding why eslint doesn't recognize the "as" operator.

[image: Error]

As you can see in the picture above, it's just giving me this generic "unexpected token" error, it's not even related to an operator misuse.

Here's a picture of my "eslintrc.js" file:

[image: eslintrc.js]

Comment: Because that's not JavaScript; it's a type assertion, it's *TypeScript*, but you haven't got any of the relevant  plugins. See e.g. https://www.npmjs.com/package/@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin

Comment: You need to use the typescript plugin for eslint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are writing in Typescript, see my eslintrc and get what you need:

```json
{
    "parser": "@typescript-eslint/parser",
    "extends": [
        "plugin:react/recommended",
        "plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended",
        "prettier/@typescript-eslint",
        "plugin:prettier/recommended"
    ],
    "parserOptions": {
        "ecmaFeatures": {
            "jsx": true
        },
        "ecmaVersion": 2020,
    },
    "rules": {

    },
    "settings": {
        "react": {
            "version": "detect"
        }
    },
    "env": {
        "browser": true,
        "es6": true
    },
}
```

If you are not, delete `as HTMLElement` because javascript can't handle it